# Using abstract class Arraylist in a tableview

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx

Good evening all,

At the moment I am stuck on a part of my project including columns. So we have class Lid and Medewerker, from the abstract class Persoon. The class Vereniging holds a Arraylist of all the Persoon and Medewerker instances called personen.

What I wanna do is create a tableview which displays all the Lid instances from that list and displays the information from the Persoon class + rol attribute from Lid class.

Classes:

Vereniging:

```
public class Vereniging {

private String naam;

private ArrayList<Persoon> personen;
private ArrayList<Vliegtuig> vliegtuigen;
private ArrayList<Vlucht> vluchten;
private ArrayList<Hangaar> hangaars;

private DataHandler handler = new Database();

public Vereniging(String naam){
    this.naam = naam;

    personen = new ArrayList<>();
    vliegtuigen = new ArrayList<>();
    vluchten = new ArrayList<>();
    hangaars = new ArrayList<>();
}

public ArrayList<Persoon> getPersonen() {
    return personen;
}
```

Persoon:

```
public abstract class Persoon implements Comparable<Persoon>{

private String voornaam;
private String tussenvoegsel;
private String achternaam;
private String woonplaats;
private String geslacht;
private String rekeningnr;

Persoon(String voornaam, String tussenvoegsel, String achternaam, String woonplaats,
               String geslacht, String rekeningnr){
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    this.tussenvoegsel = tussenvoegsel;
    this.achternaam = achternaam;
    this.woonplaats = woonplaats;
    this.geslacht = geslacht;
    this.rekeningnr = rekeningnr;
}
```

Lid:

```
public class Lid extends Persoon {

private String gebnaam;
private String wachtwoord;
private String rol;

public Lid(String voornaam, String tussenvoegsel, String achternaam, String woonplaats, String geslacht,
           String rekeningnr, String gebnaam, String wachtwoord, String rol) {
    super(voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, woonplaats, geslacht, rekeningnr);
    this.gebnaam = gebnaam;
    this.wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
    this.rol = rol;
}
```

Medewerker:

```
public class Medewerker extends Persoon {

private double salaris;

public Medewerker(String voornaam, String tussenvoegsel, String achternaam, String woonplaats,
                  String geslacht, String rekeningnr, double salaris) {
    super(voornaam, tussenvoegsel, achternaam, woonplaats, geslacht, rekeningnr);
    this.salaris = salaris;
}
```

Comment: Can you state explicitly what the problem is? What have you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: @popo Why is that a problem?